# Rails 4 error: The scope body needs to be callable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have an industry model.

I'm trying to make an index of industries, and list them alphabetically.

I have an industry.rb with:

```
  scope :alphabetically, order("sector ASC")
```

I have an index controller with:

```
  def index
    @industries = Industry.alphabetically
  end
```

In my index view, I have:

```
<% @industries.each do |industry| %>            
          <tr>
            <td><%= image_tag industry.icon.tiny.url %></td>
            <td><%= industry.sector %></td> 
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', industry %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_industry_path(industry) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', industry, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
         <% end %>
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in IndustriesController#index
The scope body needs to be callable.
```

How do I make a scope 'callable'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the error message, the scope's body needs to be wrapped within something callable like a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) or [Lambda](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F). Like this:

```
scope :alphabetically, -> {
  order("sector ASC")
}
```

This ensures the contents of the block is evaluated each time the scope is being used.

So, if you change your scope as shown above, it should work and fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's difficult to extract that information out of the error messages when they are written for people that know a lot more about what is expected.